# Measurement of highly resistive samples with Keithley 2182a nanovoltmeter

Tags: low-voltage

In our laboratory we are measuring transport properties of various materials. Currently we have deployed Keithley 2182a nanovoltmeter.

When measuring *bulk mineral* (tetrahedrites, Cu12Sb4S13 Peru) samples with high resistance (*over 10^5 Ohm* below 20K), the measurement seems to react as if we measure a capacitor, when the sample is electrically connected to the grounded chassis of the measurement cell. On the other hand, we measure a sawtooth signal, when the sample is electrically insulated.

For clarity sake we have tried to do the experiment only with a 10^6 Ohm resistor connected directly to the nanovoltmeter (original LEMO connectors, copper clips), so the diagram can be reduced straight to resistor connected to the voltmeter. The resistor naturally should not produce any voltage.

We have also observed, that duration of the measurement in number of power line cycles strongly affects the result. With several repetitions of measurement step the result looked somehow like this:

[image: The voltage measured with different measuring times, reproducible with both samples in experimental cell and resistor connected directly to the nanovoltmeter. Inset shows the sawtooth signal we obtained with samples with highest resistances, when properly electrically insulated.]

The voltage measured with different measuring times, reproducible with both samples in experimental cell and resistor connected directly to the nanovoltmeter. Inset shows the sawtooth signal we obtained with samples with highest resistances, when properly electrically insulated.

Does anybody happen to know, what are we measuring? (This question is out of practical purposes, the nanovoltmeter is purposed to measure low resistance samples, but it would be nice to know some background anyway)

Comment: Can you diagram your two experiments? What are all the instruments involved and how are they connected to each other and to the sample? Can you give more description of what is the construction of the "measurement cell"?

Comment: My gut reaction, upon reading "... we are measuring transport properties of various materials ...," is that you are asking a specialist physics question (which you should be one of) to non-specialists. Unless, that is, you are just questioning the Keithley device. But in that case, you should be calling Keithley as they will have physicists and electronics specialists available to help you. This just really seems like the wrong place to get a meaningful answer. Have you called Keithley, yet?

Comment: What do you call "high resistance?" MOhms,  GOhms, or what?

Comment: All materials are either mainly conductive or mainly insulators.  All insulators are dielectrics and all dielectrics are capacitors between conductors. The sawtooth You are seeing is what is called Partial Discharge or PD in a dielectric. What is it? animal,,vegetable or mineral? If can't share details expect 30 dumb questions

Comment: Schematic diagram of the situation? Voltmeters don't measure resistance so there must be more to it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, we greatly appreciate your input. I added requested details for the question. (Minerals, R > 10^5 Ohm, we have reproduced the odd results with resistor directly connected to the voltmeter) .

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure as 'transport properties'? Resistance is only meaningful if you first proofed a linear U-I-Curve. Is that your aim? If yes, where does the current come from? Please post a picture and a block diagram of the measurement setup. Is the 2182 on autorange or fixed range? Please also describe your sample, as temperature dependencies (sample heating) and thermocouple voltages may matter on this voltage scale.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2004 manual, page 3-8 discusses digital filter.  Is this filter turned off?  If this filter is in use, and set to 'repeating' mode, it may convert any random noise into strange jumps in readings.

Also in the manual, I see on page 2-9, the the internal A/D creates hundreds of nA on the input, and for high-resistance loads (or disconnected input leads,) creates significant millivolts artifacts.

It appears that this voltmeter is designed for measuring junction voltages on good conductors, and will produce unwanted noise if connected to high-resistance samples.

Test: disconnect the lemo jack, see if the unwanted signal is still there.  If yes, then it's caused by the meter itself.

Comment: Thanks! The reported behaviour was observed without analog or digital filter. They alter the behaviour (and I hope eventually we will master their use) but for the understanding of the problem we have omitted them so far. The signal is not present when the lemo connector is disconnected.